# Sort one Part of json array respectively to other part of same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json array

```
[
 {Age: "01-10 Days", EventName: "Invoice AP Review", Value: 1, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "01-10 Days", EventName: "Invoice Distribution", Value: 5, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "01-10 Days", EventName: "Invoice Pay Pending", Value: 2, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "10-20 Days", EventName: "Invoice AP Review", Value: 1, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "10-20 Days", EventName: "Invoice Approval", Value: 2, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "10-20 Days", EventName: "Invoice Distribution", Value: 11, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "10-20 Days", EventName: "Invoice Paid", Value: 1, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "10-20 Days", EventName: "Invoice Pay Pending", Value: 2, ActiveInvoices: []}
]
```

Please help me to sort this into array below in javascript. EventName field should come respectively for Age fields like 01-10 Days and 10-20 Days. I made and try on this jsfiddle.. please check.
http://jsfiddle.net/h829p07n/1/

```
// Required Output
[
{Age: "01-10 Days", EventName: "Invoice AP Review", Value: 1, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "01-10 Days", EventName: "Invoice Distribution", Value: 5, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "01-10 Days", EventName: "Invoice Pay Pending", Value: 2, ActiveInvoices: []}             
,{Age: "10-20 Days", EventName: "Invoice AP Review", Value: 1, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "10-20 Days", EventName: "Invoice Distribution", Value: 11, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "10-20 Days", EventName: "Invoice Pay Pending", Value: 2, ActiveInvoices: []}
,{Age: "10-20 Days", EventName: "Invoice Approval", Value: 2, ActiveInvoices: []}  
,{Age: "10-20 Days", EventName: "Invoice Paid", Value: 1, ActiveInvoices: []}
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Please provide me the javascript code to..." I don't think you understand what this site is for. It is NOT a way to get other people to do your work for you for free. It IS a way for you to get help on specific bugs in code you have written yourself. Unless you show some effort, this question will likely be closed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h829p07n/1/ 
Please check this Fiddle.. i tried here...

Comment: You may want to look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VAKrE/105/

Comment: You should include any relevant code in your question. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Basically Passing this data to kendo bar chart. due to non respective fields   its not displaying the data on correct bar .. @Phylogenesis ..

Comment: @forgivenson .. I have edited the question.. Please check Jsfiddle..

Comment: @RahulVarma .. I just checked it, Thats not related to my question.

Comment: take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/h829p07n/7/

Answer (score 0):

you have some mistakes in your code within the last for loop  (var count is not properly used)
see here a demo http://jsfiddle.net/h829p07n/7/

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < tempArra.length-1 ; i++){
   count = tempArra[i].length;
    for(var k = 0; k < count ; k++){
        for(var L = 0; L < count; L++){
            if(tempArra[i][k].EventName != tempArra[i+1][L].EventName){
                    NewArray.push(tempArra[i+1][L]);
            }else{
                if(tempArra[i][k] != undefined){
                 CommonArray.push(tempArra[i][k]) ;
                }
                if(tempArra[i+1][L] != undefined){
                    CommonArray.push(tempArra[i+1][L]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no we will not reset count in this loop.. I am getting count for maximum array of exist in tempArray.. I have to put check weather key exist or not... it also not giving require output...